# How can import a wsdl file in Delphi offline?

Tags: delphi, wsdl

I have a web service and an outsource company will use my service. I don't want to open my service to the internet. I want to give only wsdl file to the outsource company. They use Delphi. Is this possible importing a wsdl file in Delphi offline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes is possible, Delphi can import a WSDL file stored locally.

In Delphi Win32 Go to 
File->New->Others->Delphi projects->WebServices->WSDL Importer

[image]

Then you get a dialog that prompts you for the location of the WSDL file.  From the WSDL, Delphi generates a unit with interfaces  for the classes and objects exposed by the webservice.  after that creates the file with the name of the service with the extension '.pas'.

[image]

In Delphi .Net Go to

Project->Add Web Reference 
Select the file to import and press "Add reference"

[image]

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!
Just provide them with the wsdl as a file. The WSDL Importer can import from a URL or from a file.